# read the description/labels of imageSet in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have created an imageSet as follows

```
imds_meta = imageSet('myDataset','recursive');
```

Now i want to get all the labels in a separate array. I have tried the following code but it didn't work. It gives me the first label only where there are 39 of them.

```
label_names = imds_meta(1 , :).Description
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many solutions and at last this works !

```
imds = imageSet('myDataset','recursive');
label_names = string.empty ;
for i=1:39
    label_names = [label_names string(imds(1,i).Description)];
end
save('meta.mat','label_names');
```

Comment: You should append elements by `label_names(end+1) =  string(imds(1,i).Description)`. This is simpler syntax and is more efficient too.